# Oracle SQL join table first row result

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have a problem with performance Query. 
Could you explain me difference between examples below. Is the first query is faster? Why?
Thanks for help

```
   SELECT t1.symbol, t3.high, t3.low, t3.timestamp 
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN (
          SELECT inn.* 
          FROM (SELECT t2.*, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY timestamp DESC)) As Rank 
                FROM Table2 t2) inn 
          WHERE inn.Rank=1
         ) t3
         ON t1.symbol = t3.symbol;
```

and

```
   SELECT t1.symbol, t2.high, t2.low, t2.timestamp 
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN (
         SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY timestamp DESC) As Rank 
         FROM Table2) t2
         ON t1.symbol = t2.symbol
         and t2.Rank =1
```

Comment: `Is the first query is faster?` ... You're the one with the actual data.  Shouldn't you be telling us which is faster?

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen said is more or less depend no your data so without data it is not possible to get any result.

Comment: The two queries should have the same execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *guaranteed* that the first is faster than the second, but there is a possible reason for it if you are observing it.  I stress - all of this is *conjecture* on my part because you have not given us a lot of information.

Query 1

I can derive T3 first, which gives me a single row because of the inn.rank predicate.  That single row can then be used to drive into T1, and (perhaps) there is an appropriate index on 'symbol' that lets be efficient.

Query 2

T2 returns multiple rows, so we *may* choose to start with T3 and drive into T2, or vice-versa, and the filtering of rank=1 is deferred until after the join.